Ensuring user-specific memory and context in multi-user chat applications with Spring AI
How does a chat application with multiple users handle memory and context?
For example:
User 1 asks questions about Java programming. The application should retain and use User 1's specific conversation history and context for accurate responses.
User 2 asks questions about Python programming. The application should retain and use User 2's specific conversation history and context for accurate responses.
How does Spring AI ensure that the correct memory or conversation history is associated with the corresponding user's prompt?
For instance, when User 1 asks a Java-related query, the system should reference only User 1's conversation history and not confuse it with User 2's context.
